# CryptographicException: Unknown private key format while trying to load p12 file

Tags: ssl, websocket, certificate, x509certificate2, unity-webgl

I have an issue, I created a certificate using certbot let's encrypt on debian for my subdomain, certificate was issued and ssl works.

I need to use that certificate for my websocket so I converted it .p12 file using command

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out certificate.p12`

However, when I try to load .p12 file using

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string certificateName, string certificatePassword)
    {
        if (certificateName == null || certificatePassword == null) return null;

        var certificates = Directory.GetFiles(
            Environment.CurrentDirectory, 
            certificateName, 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories
        );

        var certificatePath = certificates.First(path => path.EndsWith(certificateName));
        
        return certificatePath != null ? new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword) : null;
    }
```

it return error

```
CryptographicException: Unknown private key format
  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.AddPrivateKey (Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS8+PrivateKeyInfo pki) [0x0006c] in <fed5abf356e4410f878747dcbee46084>:0
  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.ReadSafeBag (Mono.Security.ASN1 safeBag) [0x000e5] in <fed5abf356e4410f878747dcbee46084>:0
  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.Decode (System.Byte[] data) [0x00242] in <fed5abf356e4410f878747dcbee46084>:0
  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12..ctor (System.Byte[] data, System.String password) [0x0000d] in <fed5abf356e4410f878747dcbee46084>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password) [0x00023] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password) [0x0001b] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0002f] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at Mono.X509PalImpl.ImportFallback (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at Mono.X509PalImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at Mono.SystemCertificateProvider.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Mono.CertificateImportFlags importFlags) [0x00017] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at Mono.SystemCertificateProvider.Mono.ISystemCertificateProvider.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Mono.CertificateImportFlags importFlags) [0x00000] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00005] in <131fc96242a743e6b00bc8a8663638a3>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0003e] in <131fc96242a743e6b00bc8a8663638a3>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password) [0x00000] in <131fc96242a743e6b00bc8a8663638a3>:0
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password) [0x00000] in <0f3a92f18c3f4515965ea9093114785a>:0
  at WebSocketListener.WebSocketNetworkListener.GetCertificate (System.String certificateName, System.String certificatePassword) [0x0004b] in C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Work\unity\Vamps\GameEngine\Assets\Networking\WebGL\WebSocketNetworkListener.cs:133
  at WebSocketListener.WebSocketNetworkListener..ctor (DarkRift.Server.NetworkListenerLoadData pluginLoadData) [0x00014] in C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Work\unity\Vamps\GameEngine\Assets\Networking\WebGL\WebSocketNetworkListener.cs:26
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
```

This is implementation of https://github.com/flejmer/DarkRift2-WebSocketListener for unity-webgl socket

Comment: I'm surprised at the number of people running into issues like this, since I thought Mono unified onto the .NET Core cryptography libraries several years ago... but, this seems to be another manifestation of "Mono.Security can't read modern PFX files".  With OpenSSL 1.1.1 the fix would be to add `-keypbe 3DES`, but I think OpenSSL 3 changed it to `-keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES`.  Try adding either of those to your pkcs12 export command and see if things get better.

Comment: @bartonjs 
Tried to export with 
```openssl pkcs12 -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out certificate.p12```

Still getting 
```CryptographicException: Unknown private key format```

If I enter wrong password it say's this
```CryptographicException: Invalid MAC - file may have been tampered with!
Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.Decode (System.Byte[] data) (at <e5993be9a0b142d1898f3a09f397f9ff>:0)
Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12..ctor (System.Byte[] data, System.String password) (at <e5993be9a0b142d1898f3a09f397f9ff>:0)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by generating certificate with option --key-type rsa

Comment: Is this in the openssl command? This gives me:
Invalid command '--key-type'; type "help" for a list. or
pkcs12: Unrecognized flag key-type depending on where in the command line I put it.